# Why am I getting notice of block from asking?

Tags: discussion

I am getting the notice:

> We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so
>   deprives future readers of this knowledge.

I want to delete this question because it got a lot of down votes. How can I delete that question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246321/why-this-code-showing-the-worng-day-of-week

Comment: You should improve your question instead of deleting it.

Comment: You might see some extra down votes due to the meta-effect....

Comment: Because your question has multiple answers, you can't actually delete it.

Comment: There is an answer for this question now. You won't be able to delete this one either

Comment: i think it is a bad day but it's going worse :(

Comment: If losing fake internet points is the only thing bad today, you're having a great day!

Comment: The title of this post doesn't seem to correspond with the actual question...

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Which is odd because I don't see any history of this user ever being blocked from asking questions. Maybe he's worried.

Comment: Have another meta downvote, partially for simply using a language where 'false' can be assigned to a calendar date.

Comment: Not sure whether that question deserved this wild amount of downvotes, but I'd just move on. There's little one can do.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Looks like they want to roast you now. I've been trying to reveal you by closing and later delete already. I think the only mind behind reopening your question can be that others had put valuable efforts in your question. Well, you have learned something today I believe. Good day so!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i learn one thing don't use stackoverflow, it is not for programming problem...

Comment: @QaisarSatti C'mon that's obviously not true. You just improve on research before asking a programming problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i have a problem.i post the problem other thing idk what include in that....

Comment: @Qaisa, the problem is that you failed to do proper research before asking. A quick glance at the docs would have solved your issue without you having to post a question at all. Your profile claims you have *extensive knowledge working with PHP*, that should include reading the docs.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  some time you stuck with simple problem and time given short.you have find to quick solution.

Comment: @Qaisar, I can understand that, but Stack Overflow is not the right tool to use in this situation. It should be your last resort when confronted to a problem, not the first.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it is my last option for go on stackoverflow. i stuck with this problem for three hour i have to deliver the work on time..

Comment: You used to get the "Peer Pressure" badge for doing that.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That question receives down votes because users probably think you should have done some research first.

Despite that, at least one user thought it was wise to answer your poor question. If it stayed at that there was not much harm. Unfortunately for you the answers were also up voted. That event basically blocked your option to [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) your question:

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes

Your only "[*hope*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168828/require-a-minimum-rep-to-delete-your-own-question/168835#168835)" now is to wait for it to get closed and some 20K-ers delete it for you. I wouldn't go for editing it into shape because I presume it might be a duplicate as well.

Comment: I'm starting to think the users that are answering low-quality questions for free rep are more selfish than the OPs who want to delete their questions because they were poorly-received despite having been answered.

Comment: can you tell how many down vote remaining. so some can do it for me

Comment: @BoltClock I was about to write nasty things about the quality consciousness of the followers of the  php tag but I choose to leave that conclusion to commenters...

Comment: @BoltClock ["behaving like hyenas just to get some extra points"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all#comment798506_244290)?

Comment: @QaisarSatti it's currently two votes each for reopen and delete. I think it should be a left as a warning to the others!

Comment: wrt "hope to delete", worth keeping in mind that question block system tends to rather heavily [penalize deleted _answered_ questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168835/165773) - meaning one would better avoid relying on such an "escape" too much (these fastest gun answerers are sometimes really like hyenas, spreading damage at everything they bite)

Comment: It'sa strange, parallel universe where a boolean can be assigned to a calendar date:)

Comment: @gnat I linky-fied hope ...tnx...

Comment: Shouldn't it be removed though? Everyone is clearly agreeing it's a poor question and that it is probably a duplicate and I can understand his point of view. Profile doesn't look good with a -14 question and counting.

Comment: *Doesn't look good on profile* is not a reason as far as I know to stop voting on posts, neither is *looks good on profile* for that matter... The link gnat provided indicate deleting might have consequences as well. Maybe flagging for a  moderator can help in this case.

Comment: @rene: A mod deletion is no different from deletion by anyone else. A deleted question counts the same way against the ban regardless of who deleted it. Save from disassociation the OP is basically screwed.